# Trying to add a second IP address to my Ubuntu machine

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to add second IP address to my machine and make them both accessible from anywhere.
Here is my configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 46.10.222.174
netmask 255.255.252.0
gateway 46.10.222.1

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 46.10.222.142
netmask 255.255.252.0
```

Right now when i try to ping from the machine itself another destination, take a look at this example what i receive:

```
ping abv.bg
ping: unknown host abv.bg
```

As you can test there is no problem to `ping abv.bg`. I do not know why i have this problem.

My second and most important problem is that i can ping and access the machine only with ip 46.10.222.174.

Why i can not access my second IP ? You can test it by your self. You can ping my first ip but you can not ping my second one, why ?

Where is my mistake?

Comment: There is no gateway setting on the second interface (not sure this is the problem but worth investigating).

Comment: Do you have permission to use the IP address that you assigned (it appears to be ISP owned)? That is to mean, did you have it assigned to you? Secondly, can you provide the output of a `netstat -rn` or an `ip route show`?

Answer (score 0):

You should (as root) create a file /etc/resolv.conf with the following lines

```
search yourdomain.com

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

This will allow DNS to work, using Googles nameserver.  The "search yourdomain.com" line is advised, but optional - if you enter in "myhost", it will look up "myhost.yourdomain.com"

Comment: As discussed, there is either a limitation associated with MAC address requirements or your ISP is not routing the second IP address to you, which is why the second domain is not working (You were not seeing the traffic on Wireshark, so its not your computers setup)